# Checking if date falls within a date range then write the date range to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to simplify some code I have written but not sure how to go about doing it. When my workbook opens it checks the current date and compares it to dates I have on a sheet. If the current date is <= date on sheet it writes the date range to a cell. My issue is I have 13 If statements and would like to simply/neaten it up.

I know there is a better way to go about if/then statements I just can't remember what it is or how to implement it.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C15").Value < Date Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C3").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C15") + 28
End If

If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C15").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B15").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C15").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B15").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C15").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C14").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B14").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C14").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B14").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C14").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C13").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B13").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C13").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B13").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C13").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C12").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B12").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C12").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B12").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C12").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C11").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B11").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C11").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B11").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C11").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C10").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B10").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C10").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B10").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C10").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C09").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B09").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C09").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B09").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C09").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C08").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B08").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C08").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B08").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C08").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C07").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B07").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C07").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B07").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C07").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C06").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B06").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C06").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B06").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C06").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C05").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B05").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C05").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B05").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C05").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C04").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B04").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C04").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B04").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C04").Value
End If
If Date <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C03").Value Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B03").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C03").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("B03").Value & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates").Range("C03").Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.  Your current title applies to virtually every question on this site, so the usual practice is to title your post with what the code is doing.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. Please read  [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). It will give you a hint on who to title the question.

Comment: @Teepeemm When a new comer to the site doesn't know that we are looking for a description of what the code does in the title, it is best to send them to the help page.

Comment: Is there any known/guaranteed relation between the values in C03…15?

Comment: So the dates are a period of time, C03 is the start date and C15 is the end date

Answer (score 3):

**DRY**

There is an important software principle called "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY).  Writing software with frequent use of Copy-Paste is the antithesis of DRY.  Not only does it cause repeated expressions with minor differences per copy - it results in code that is difficult to change, debug, and maintain. The purpose of the code is lost in all the *typing*.

**Code-Behind/Error Handling**

The code provided is initiated by the `Open_Workbook` event.  When your users open this workbook, the Excel application/workbook becomes the initial User-Interface.  It is usually a best practice to have as little logic as possible (other than UI logic) in these objects.  The code in UI objects is generally referred to as the 'code-behind'.  If it is important, in general, to have as little code as possible in the code-behind...then it is especially important when the Workbook object acts as a UI.

The more code/logic within the Workbook object (or any object for that matter), the greater the chance of errors and exceptions.  If simply opening the workbook is going to 'kick-off' any kind of operation, then it would seem especially prudent to gracefully handle startup errors.

So, it would be advisable to move all the initialization code to a dedicated Standard Module.  Call this module from the `Workbook_Open` event and protect against any errors/exceptions propagating back to the Workbook object without a handler.  Further, the call to the dedicated module can take Date object as a parameter.  Doing so makes it easy to test or initiate the setup code without having to close and re-open the workbook (example provided below).

The objects below implement the suggestions above.

*ThisWorkbook*

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Not SetupModule.TrySetupWorksheets(Date) Then
        MsgBox "Error encountered during startup"
    End If
End Sub
```

*SetupModule.bas*

````
Option Explicit

'Initiate the process for test/debugging by calling this macro from Developer -> Macros
Public Sub Test()
    If TrySetupWorksheets(Date) Then
        MsgBox "TestFailed"
    End If
End Sub

Public Function TrySetupWorksheets(ByVal currentDate As Date) As Boolean

    TrySetupWorksheets = False
    
On Error GoTo ErrorExit
    Dim periodDatesSheet As Worksheet
    Set periodDatesSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Period Dates")
    
    SetupPeriodDates currentDate, periodDatesSheet
    
    Dim columnCValue As Variant
    
    Dim rowNumber As Long
    For rowNumber = 15 To 3 Step -1
        columnCValue = periodDatesSheet.Range("C" & CStr(rowNumber)).Value
        If currentDate <= columnCValue Then
            WriteDateExpressionToCells periodDatesSheet.Range("B" & CStr(rowNumber)).Value & " - " & columnCValue
        End If
    Next
    TrySetupWorksheets = True
    
ErrorExit:
End Function

Private Sub SetupPeriodDates(ByVal currentDate As Date, ByVal periodDatesSheet As Worksheet)
    If periodDatesSheet.Range("C15").Value < currentDate Then
        periodDatesSheet.Range("C3").Value = periodDatesSheet.Range("C15") + 28
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WriteDateExpressionToCells(ByVal dateExpression As Variant)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("North Reading").Range("B2").Value = dateExpression
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Chelmsford St").Range("B2").Value = dateExpression
End Sub
  
End Sub

```
````